# How to ensure HSQLDB properties configuration loaded on Windows?

Tags: java, windows, window, hsqldb

I have a problem with HSQLDB V2.3 on Windows.  I can't connect with new databases using the **HSQLDB Server**.

1. Is there a log or debug option for the server so I can check the properties loaded and file paths, etc?
2. Is my properties file OK?  I wasn't sure how to formulate file paths for windows.

   - Can I use quotes on file path names?
3. Is the connection string I'm using for the **tmp** db correct?
4. What's the correct syntax to use the **--props** server argument?

   - --props path
   - --props path/filename

I have set-up two environment variables (too keep it simple*).  These variables don't have any effect except to save my typing.  Initially I was loading the server from the HSQLDB folder directly.

- HSQLDB_HOME ... home folder for the current HSQLDB
- HSQLDB_DATA ... folder for data repository

I am following the the steps from:

- 1. [Running and Using HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/running-chapt.html)

Every time I connect via the server it makes a database called, "test" instead of letting me connect to either of the two databases specified in the server.properties.

- %HSQLDB_DATA%/

  - test.log
  - test.properties
  - test.script
  - test.tmp/  .......... (folder)
  - test.lck

I made a '**server.properties**' file in:

- %HSQLDB_HOME%/lib/

where the HSQLDB JAR file is.  I want two databases: **tmp** and **dev**:

```
  # -- tmp
  server.database.0=file:hsqldb/tmp_db/tmp
  server.dbname.0=tmp_db
  #
  ####
  #
  # -- dev
  server.database.1=file:r:/.data/hsqldb/dev_db/dev
  server.dbname.1=dev_db
```

I expected that the properties file to be enough to set-up two databases.  When I run the hsqldb manager I don't get a connection for tmp say:

- "jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/tmp"
- user: SA, password: ""

I get a pop-up error:

- database alias does not exist (*Manager*)
- [Thread[HSQLDB Connection @26827674,5,HSQLDB Connections @372f7a8d]]: database alias=tmp does not exist (*Server*)

I created these two manually using the *cmd*-line, e.g. named "***tmp***":

- %JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe -classpath %HSQLDB_HOME%\lib\hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.server.Server org.hsqldb.server.Server  --database.1 file:**r:/.data/hsqldb/tmp_db**  --dbname.1 tmp_db

And could connect and create tmp:

- %HSQLDB_DATA%/tmp_db/

  - tmp.log
  - tmp.properties
  - tmp.script
  - tmp.tmp/  .......... (folder)
  - tmp.lck

as forecast in the [documentation](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/running-chapt.html).  When I start-up the HSQLDB Server with the aforesaid '***server.properties***' file or specifying properties explicitly:

- %JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe -classpath %HSQLDB_HOME%\lib\hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.server.Server --trace true  --props %HSQLDB_DATA%

The server will only let me connect with a database called "test" as described at the beginning of the question.

Because the properties file looks good and the in-process file connection string works,

- jdbc:hsqldb:hsqldb/tmp_db/tmp

I am left considering that the server.properties file is in the wrong place or not loading for some reason.  It would be wonderful if there's a way for the server to dump the properties file at start-time :-)  Thanks in advance for your suggestions ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the problem.  Firstly, thanks to this tutorial:

- [HSQLDB Installation](http://www.seasar.org/en/tutorial/hsqldb/setup/)

After reviewing this I realised my error.

The **server.properties** file must be in the current folder when the server script runs.  I had read that on the [Running and Using HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/running-chapt.html) manual page but misinterpreted its meaning and I put the properties file in my %HSQLDB_HOME%/lib folder.  Oops.

When you look at the BAT script, it actually changed the current folder to be the **%HSQLDB_HOME%/data** folder ...

- cd ..\data

So the default location for your server.properties file should be your: %HSQLDB_HOME%/data if you want to work with the default runServer.bat script.

For those wanting to separate data from the server software.  I made an improvement for the default script using the two environment variables as follows.

- HSQLDB_HOME ... home folder for the current HSQLDB
- HSQLDB_DATA ... folder for data repository

**runServer**.bat:

```
   @cd /d %HSQLDB_DATA%
   @cd
   @echo.
   @rem __ @pause
   %JAVA_HOME%\bin\java -classpath %HSQLDB_HOME%\lib\hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.server.Server     %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
   @echo.
   @pause
```

Which now expects my server.properties file in the %HSQL_DATA% folder.  And that works.  Also for my server since it is for development /testing, I'm using the *--trace=true* option.  Like a lot of these things, now I get-it, it all makes perfect sense.  Hopefully my misunderstanding will assist others who haven't found a simple tutorial before resorting to stackoverflow.